# How to represent operations in WebAssembly Text format?

Tags: webassembly

Let's say I am writing the following C code in WebAssembly Text format:

```c
if (a < 2) a = 5;
else a = 6;
```

WASM:

```lisp
(if
  (i32.eq (get_local $x) (i32.const 10))
  (then (i32.local 5) (set_local $x))
  (else (i32.const 7) (local.set $a))
)
```

This also works:

```lisp
(
    ;; ....
    get_local $a
    i32.const 2
    i32.lt_s ;; a < 2  
    (if
        (then
            i32.const 5
            local.set $a
        )
        (else 
            i32.const 7
            local.set $a
        )
    )
    ;; ...
)
```

Which one to follow? Why the difference over writing operations before and after the operands?

Answer (score 1):

It is purely a matter of personal preference -- the assembled code is the same. Which style do you prefer? (But I must say, your WASM code doesn't do what your C code does!)

Answer (score 0):

Webassembly text format is a (virtual) stack machine, meaning you can only add and remove things from the end of a stack (think list).

```
i32.const 10 ;;stack=[10]
i32.const 6 ;;stack=[10, 6]
i32.const 2 ;;stack=[10, 6, 2]
i31.add ;;consume two from stack and then put result on stack. stack=[10, 8]
i32.add ;;consume two from stack and then put result on stack. stack=[18]
```

This is how webassembly text format behaves, however you are allowed to use parenthesis ([S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)) to choose the order they are put on the stack.

```
(i32.const 98 (i32.const 3)) ;;stack=[3, 98]
```

Allowing for much easier (for humans) to read syntax eg:

```
(i32.add (i32.const 10) (i32.add (i32.const 6) (i32.const 2)) ;;stack=[18]
```

So to answer your question: It doesnt matter which you use but if you are writing .wat by hand its clearly easier to use s-expressions.